# instantiate DAO only if configured

Tags: security, authorization, roles

Could anyone please tell me the best approach to resolve the user privilege set if a user is a member of multiple groups that grant non-orthogonal sets of privileges?  In the world of authorization, how do we usually deal with the issue (taking the least privilege set, or taking the maximum privilege set, or somewhere in the middle, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of the context of your question but I'll try to answer in general. When you have a user who is part of multiple orthogonal groups you:

1. Use RBAC and assign the user to multiple roles. This would be giving the user the union/maximum privilege set.
2. Give the user multiple accounts, one per group. For example, you could have the users `alex_student` and `alex_teacher` if the student Alex also teaches.
3. Give the user a minimal set of privileges and allow them to temporarily change them. Something like `sudo` that works for non-overlapping privileges.